# How can I run VMs on Container Linux?

Tags: kvm, coreos, rkt

I've been investigating CoreOS's [Container Linux](https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/) recently and was wondering if there's a 'nice' way to run Container Linux VMs on Container Linux, possibly with rkt.

I understand rkt has a [KVM stage 1](https://coreos.com/rkt/docs/latest/running-kvm-stage1.html) so was wondering how easy it is to use Container Linux as the kernel for that.

Comment: I am currently researching the same topic. I'm interested to see if I could install `Container Linux` on bare metal and then run `VMs` via `KVM` on it (legacy windows vms...). Did you find if it's possible?

Comment: So yesterday I was reading about something that might work from kinvolk https://kinvolk.io/blog/2017/02/using-custom-rkt-stage1-images-to-test-against-various-kernel-versions/ - for running their CI jobs they spin up VMs using rkt's KVM stage 1 with a custom kernel and explain in that post how to build an ACI image with a custom kernel. I'm currently trying to learn how to compile the Linux kernel to do this, but I don't see why you couldn't use Windows instead - I'd be very interested to hear if you make progress with that

Comment: Interesting reading! I'll be trying this out over the next few weeks and let you know in case I manage to get it to work. Thanks for sharing! :)

Comment: Hey, I've just stumbled on [this gist](https://gist.github.com/dghubble/c2dc319249b156db06aff1d49c15272e) which shows how you can run `QEMU` VMs. Basically you start a privileged container which gives access to `/dev/kvm` and from there you can install `QEMU` inside your container and start your VMs.  We'll be trying this out soon and decided to share it in case anybody else is looking for something similar. Don't forget to checkout the video as well https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tlUiQa2JYQU :)